# Bootstrap 3 side by side containers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a webpage where the left-half of my content respect the bootstrap `.container` max-width size, while my right side can go all the way to the end of the page, as a `.container-fluid` would work.

Something like this image:

[image]

So far I've tried a couple of methods, currently I'm sitting on the following code:

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla iaculis feugiat est, eu suscipit quam elementum id. Sed nec scelerisque ex. Nunc consectetur vulputate ante, non fermentum odio dignissim nec. Aenean a lectus auctor, suscipit diam vitae, tincidunt ante. Nulla ultrices iaculis orci, a rhoncus nisi consectetur sed. Quisque eget viverra tellus. Cras ac lacinia nibh. Maecenas non dui ut urna aliquet tristique ut a </p>      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-6">
                    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla iaculis feugiat est, eu suscipit quam elementum id. Sed nec scelerisque ex. Nunc consectetur vulputate ante, non fermentum odio dignissim nec. Aenean a lectus auctor, suscipit diam vitae, tincidunt ante. Nulla ultrices iaculis orci, a rhoncus nisi consectetur sed. Quisque eget viverra tellus. Cras ac lacinia nibh. Maecenas non dui ut urna aliquet tristique ut a </p>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Which produces the following result:

[image]

Comment: One container, one row, two columns. Both columns have their own containers, each container have their own row, each row have their own column.

Comment: The container is a block element.  It will take up 100% of the width by default.  So, your containers will not sit beside each other.

Comment: @sksallaj Something like this? https://pastebin.com/ZmQvxg9m

Comment: @adpro No way to make it happen then?

Comment: There are ways to happen. See my answer. It would be best to re-think your markup, but if you wanted to keep the markup you can do something similar to what I did in my answer.

Comment: @adpro Thanks for the answer, my problem is gonna be aligning the flex content with the rest of my bootstrap, but it seems to be the best way to solve it.

Comment: @AntonioNeto no, this is what I was talking about... https://jsfiddle.net/8w1fbnhk/3/   You have one container, with one row and two columns, then in each column, you make a container with a row and a col, and put your content there. then you can make your styles on each column (with extra padding, margins, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current markup, you could do this:

```css
.container .row {
    padding: 30px;
}

.container-fluid[class*="col-"], .container[class*="col-"] {
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <div class="container col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla iaculis feugiat est, eu suscipit quam elementum id. Sed nec scelerisque ex. Nunc consectetur vulputate ante, non fermentum odio dignissim nec. Aenean a lectus auctor, suscipit diam vitae, tincidunt ante. Nulla ultrices iaculis orci, a rhoncus nisi consectetur sed. Quisque eget viverra tellus. Cras ac lacinia nibh. Maecenas non dui ut urna aliquet tristique ut a </p>      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla iaculis feugiat est, eu suscipit quam elementum id. Sed nec scelerisque ex. Nunc consectetur vulputate ante, non fermentum odio dignissim nec. Aenean a lectus auctor, suscipit diam vitae, tincidunt ante. Nulla ultrices iaculis orci, a rhoncus nisi consectetur sed. Quisque eget viverra tellus. Cras ac lacinia nibh. Maecenas non dui ut urna aliquet tristique ut a </p>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I would suggest re-thinking the markup, though.  `container` may not be your best choice here.  It seems [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) might be a good solution as well.

Comment: Remember to hit "Full page" to see the snippet in a larger than xs width.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.container .row {
    padding: 30px;
}

.container-fluid, .container {
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <div class="container col-md-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1 class="text-center">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                    <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla iaculis feugiat est, eu suscipit quam elementum id. Sed nec scelerisque ex. Nunc consectetur vulputate ante, non fermentum odio dignissim nec. Aenean a lectus auctor, suscipit diam vitae, tincidunt ante. Nulla ultrices iaculis orci, a rhoncus nisi consectetur sed. Quisque eget viverra tellus. Cras ac lacinia nibh. Maecenas non dui ut urna aliquet tristique ut a </p>      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid col-md-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1 class="text-center">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                    <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla iaculis feugiat est, eu suscipit quam elementum id. Sed nec scelerisque ex. Nunc consectetur vulputate ante, non fermentum odio dignissim nec. Aenean a lectus auctor, suscipit diam vitae, tincidunt ante. Nulla ultrices iaculis orci, a rhoncus nisi consectetur sed. Quisque eget viverra tellus. Cras ac lacinia nibh. Maecenas non dui ut urna aliquet tristique ut a </p>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer