# Asymmetric bootstrap layout - background from side to content area

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achive this on bootstrap 4 website (it can be bootstrap 3 or even plain html/css but preferebly not javascript). Problem is that I cannot find the way to position background (and in second example content - google map) to reach screen end from one side and only end of container block on other side.

[image: asymetric bootstrap layout]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Here are a few very similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137284/bootstrap-3-side-by-side-containers, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002070/extend-bootstrap-row-outside-the-container/42002499

Comment: Also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564131/bootstrap-full-width-with-2-different-backgrounds-and-2-columns

Comment: Paulie_D - Thank You, these may work.

Comment: Also CSS Grid - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/geYJeB